# Putting content next to vertical navigation

Tags: css, multiple-columns

I know this should be simple, but I can't figure it out. I want to have a vertical navigation menu on the left side of a page with the main content of the page next to it. In this example, I want GOOGLY GOOGLY to display to the right of the menu, not below it. How do I make both columns start at the top? Thank you!

[updated--sorry about the copy-paste problem]

CSS

```
#vamain
{
 float: left;
 width: 100;
}


#vowelaltnav
{
/*avoid gap after li in ie6 by setting width*/
float: left
width: 130px;
font-size: 11px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
margin-left: 30px;
}

#vowelaltnav ul
{
list-style-type: none;
margin-left: 0;
padding-left: 0;
}

#navlist a
{
display: block;
color: #8592BB;
padding: 8px 0 8px 8px;
}

/*boxmodel hack. http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=BoxModelHack SBMH*/
#navlist a { width: 114px; }

#navlist a
{
\width: 130px;
w\idth: 114px;
}

#subnavlist a
{
display: block;
color: #9C9C9C;
padding: 8px 0 8px 8px;
margin-left: 8px;
}

/*boxmodel hack. http://css-discuss.incutio.com/?page=BoxModelHack SBMH*/
#subnavlist a { width: 106px; }

#subnavlist a
{
\width: 122px;
w\idth: 106px;
}

#navlist a, #navlist a:visited,#subnavlist a, #subnavlist a:visited
{
border-left: 8px solid #FFFFFF;
background: #FFFFFF;
color: #9C9C9C;
text-decoration: none;
}

#navlist a:hover, #navlist a#current:hover
{
border-left: 8px solid #CCCCCC;
text-decoration: underline;
}

#subnavlist a:hover, #subnavlist a#subcurrent:hover
{
border-left: 8px solid #CCCCCC;
text-decoration: underline;
}

a#current, a:visited#current, a#subcurrent , a:visited#subcurrent
{
border-left: 8px solid #283D82;
background: #F3F5FC;
color: #283D82;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="vowelaltnav">
<ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a> 
<ul id="subnavlist">
<li id="subactive"><a href="#" id="subcurrent">Subitem one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Subitem two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Subitem three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Subitem four</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="vamain">
<p> GOOGLY GOOGLY </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Right--sorry. Fixed now, I think.

Comment: Good point, thank you, but it doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/VWSEB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of typos in your CSS which contribute to it not working correctly. Here are the ones you need to fix:

Line 3: `Width: 100;` -> `width: 100px;`
Line 11: `float: left` -> `float: left;`
Line 37, 38, 54, 55: Remove the slashes from `width`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpr38/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to go back and clean up your CSS.
you have:

```
#navlist a
{
\width: 130px;
w\idth: 114px;
}
```

first, both widths' have erroneous \'s in them
second, why do you have two widths in the same css tag?

You will find it much easier later down the road if you go back and do these things now. Trust me, I am a new developer myself and have encountered similar problems because of lazy coding earlier on.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to `float: left` or `display: inline-block` on both `#vowelaltnav` and `#vamain`